# How can I use an online search engine through Python?

Tags: python, database, search-engine

I'm wondering whether it's possible to use an online search engine within Python to search through thousands of search items all at once.

Essentially, I have 3000+ bits of data (coordinates to be specific). There's a website online that can take these coordinates and spit out what it's closest to (in some vague sense -- the specifics aren't important).

So, I want to be able to put all 3000 into the search engine and get 3000 answers efficiently without having to submit each search query one at a time. Is there a way to use an online search engine that someone else created in this sense?

Comment: you have to use the api provided by the search engines. for google its very well documented.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this answer can help you, except it will open new 3000 tabs so maybe it's not efficient, but it's better than submit each query search:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38462948/13069878

```
import webbrowser
search_terms = []

# ... construct your list of search terms ...

for term in search_terms:
    url = "https://www.google.com.tr/search?q={}".format(term)
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```